# How to measure area under the waveform (electric current)?

Tags: electricity, waves, electric-circuits

I have a current waveform from my circuit which goes up and down the x-axis.

x-axis represents time and my y axis represents current. How should I calculate total area under the curve? Should I take the absolute for negative part of current or just waveform integral will work?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do.

The integral will give you the net current. So if you did the integral for the AC current going to the computer I'm typing this on you'd get the value zero. This is quite correct because no net current flows for kit powered by AC. On the other hand, if you're trying to work out how much *power* my computer consumes you integrate $I^2$ not $I$ because power = $I^2R$. Since $I^2$ is always positive you now get a positive result.

I'm not sure why you'd want to integrate $|I|$, i.e. *take the absolute for negative part of current*. It's not obvious what you would calculate using this.